# Data size boom when save dataframe as parquet in HDFS using Spark

Tags: apache-spark-sql, parquet

I save dataframe dfA with 500M rows as parquet format and snappy compression on hdfs with size 10GB in partition a. Then I load this data and join with other data source with size 300MB to generate a new dataFrame dfB, when I save it in the same table with dataframe dfA in another partition b. Compare to dfA, dfB only increase 1M rows, but the data size of dfB increase to 30GB. dfA and dfB save in same format with same columns, I wonder why the data size of dfB boom compare to dfA?

Comment: How many parquet parts are created at each step? It might happen that dfA is 10GB spread across 100 physical parquet parts, whereas dfB is spread across a 1000 physical parts. This may greatly affect encoding efficiency....
You might also check the parquet rowgroup size (use parquet-tools) of dfA and dfB, though if you did not knowingly change it, I doubt you'll find any difference. Too small row groups would result in poor encoding as well...

Comment: I user parquet-tool to analyze the files saved for dfA and dfB, the "TS" of parquet file dfA is quite large than the file size dsiplayed, whereas "TS" of dfB equals the file size.